# Admob native ads destroy() method inside a recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, native-ads

I'm using admob native ads template. Admob recommends to use the destroy() method on native ads to avoid memory leaks. It recommends to call the method inside the onDestroy() method of an activity.

```
if (isDestroyed()) {
            ad.destroy();
            return;
        }
```

I'm using the recyclerview and I've initialized the ad at mainactivity as

```
MobileAds.initialize(MainActivity.this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
```

but I've placed the rest of the ads codes inside the recyclerview adapter using the get itemviewtype

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

if (getItemViewType(position) == AD_TYPE){

            final AdLoader adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110")
                    .forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                            // Show the ad.
                            NativeTemplateStyle styles = new
                                    NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().build();

                            TemplateView template = ((adViewHolder) holder).Adtemplate;
                            template.setStyles(styles);
                            template.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);

                        }
                    })
                    .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                            // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                        }
                    })
                    .withNativeAdOptions(new NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                            // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                            // used here to specify individual options settings.
                            .build())
                    .build();
            adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());


        }
```

where should i perform the ad.destroy() method in this scenario? Also, do i need to perform any other methods for the native ads templates? Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own function for destroy ads and call it from activity `onDestroy`

In Your Adapter make a function like this

```
public void destroyAds() {
    ad.destroy();
}
```

And from activity `onDestroy()` call that function

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    adapter.destroyAds();
}
```

Comment: Yes that would be perfect. Could you tell me how could  i pass the (UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) parameter from onBindView to the onDestroy method created in the adapter?

Comment: you can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58626477/ads-in-recyclerview if you want they use ads in `recyclerview ` and destroy it in activity